# Could not find gem 'puma (= 3.9.1) x64-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

while I tries to run rails server command it alwayes shows the error..

Comment: have you tried `bundle install` or `bundle update`?

Answer (score 0):

Running 'bundle update' fixed this up for me.

Running on debian 10.8 under wsl 2. I'm installing into system directories, so I did have to supply my password for a sudo.